# Mysql export piped to another mysql server using a custom query

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I am trying to do an export of a table in 1 mysql server and pipe the data directly to the new sql server.

Lets say that I have a `User` Table that has 2 groups of users `group = 1` or `group = 2`

What i want to do is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `User`.`group`=1 | mysql -h newhost.com -u root -p dbname newTable
```

Some of these queries will have joins if that makes a difference

I have tried:

```
mysql -e"SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `User`.`group`=1" -u root -pxxxxxxx dbname| mysql -h newhost.com -u root -pxxxxxxxxx newDbName NewUserTable
```

This for some reason just throws tons of errors. It looks like it opens the mysql terminal then it just shows usage info.

Heres a closer example to what I am trying to do:

```
mysqldump -u root -pxxxxxxxx dbname Article --no_create_info --max-allowed-packet=1073741824 --lock-all-tables --where 'article_id in (SELECT article_id FROM Article LEFT JOIN Client on Article.client = Client.client_id LEFT JOIN Company on Client.company = Company.company_id WHERE Company.name="Company1")' | mysql -h rds.amazonaws.com -u root -pxxxxxxxx newdbname Article
```

When i run this in the terminal i get the mysql usage options output followed by:
`mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

**SOLUTION**

Using mysqldump i was able to use a custom where statement that had a nested select that selected the ids of the table i was looking to move.

> NOTE: When using nested SELECT you must include the table name with the column name. IE Table1.column1.  Also make sure that all of your options come before your database name. And finally when piping the data to the mysql server do not include the table name after the database.

Final working command:

```
mysqldump -u root -pxxxxxxxx --no_create_info --max-allowed-packet=1073741824 --lock-all-tables --where 'article_id in (SELECT Article.article_id FROM Article LEFT JOIN Client on Article.client = Client.client_id LEFT JOIN Company on Client.company = Company.company_id WHERE Company.name="Company1")' dbname Article | mysql -h rds.amazonaws.com -u root -pxxxxxxxx newdbname
```

Comment: You can give `WHERE` clauses to `mysqldump`. For more complex queries, I'd `CREATE TABLE sometablename AS SELECT ...some complex query...`, and `mysqldump` that one.

Comment: @Wrikken What about the ones where the WHERE needs join fields?

Comment: added that in my original comment right after.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating additional tables / files, i could just export the query to a file then import it into the new table i was just wondering if it was possible to skip the middle steps and just pipe it there directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Using `mysqldump` with the table & `where` clause set.

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [password] [dbname] User --no_create_info --where="User.group=1" | mysql -h [hostname] -u [root] -p [dbname]
```

More details on more elaborate queries using `mysqldump` [can be found here](http://krosinski.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-table-join-with-mysqldump.html). Including an example of how to hook a `join` into the query with this example:

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p db_name table_name --no_create_info \
--lock-all-tables --where 'id in (select tn.id from table_name as tn \
join related_table as rt on tn.related_table_id = rt.id \
where rt.some_field = 1)' > data.sql
```

The basic idea is the `where` clause has it’s own query which would do what I believe you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This will work for tables that dont rely on joins for the where clause. But what about the ones that dont?

Comment: Let me give that a try, looks promising though

Comment: I try to run the command and it keeps spiting out the usage options then says `mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

Comment: I figured it out, You cant have the table name on the end of the pipe, the mysqldump handles the table name. If you want to remove that from your answer ill accept it.