# Mysqldump with left join ignores the join

Tags: mysql

I use the command:

```
mysqldump -u user-pPW --no_create_info --lock-all-tables --where 'exists (SELECT strais.inventar2.ean, bezeichnung, art, stammkost, marker FROM strais.inventar2 LEFT JOIN strais.inventar_pool ON strais.inventar2.ean = strais.inventar_pool.ean WHERE strais.inventar2.ean = strais.inventar_pool.ean)' strais inventar2 > inventar.sql
```

to create a sql file. It works, but the join-command is ignored. Only the SELECT query is used and the LEFT JOIN seems to be ignored. Why?

PS: After this step I'll convert the sql to sqlite file.

PS2: I followed: [Mysql export piped to another mysql server using a custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624105/mysql-export-piped-to-another-mysql-server-using-a-custom-query)